# Android RatingBar aligned right

Tags: android

I have a custom rating bar in which i edited from this tutorial (http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/)

I only want to show full cookies and not empty ones hence i replaced the empty-cookie.png with just a transparent image.

My problem is, in my UI i want my visible cookies to be right aligned, in other words, to be shown from right to left instead of the current left to right.

How can i achieve that? i DO NOT NEED to show half cookies and this is only used as an indicator (`android:isIndicator="true"`)

Alternate non-ratingbar solutions are welcomed too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this by setting visibilities of multiple ImageViews stored in an array and displayed using a RelativeLayout in the end.

```
private void setClocksVisible(int numClocks) {
    if(numClocks == 0 || numClocks == -1) {
        for(int i=0; i< holder.ratingClocks.length; i++) {
            holder.ratingClocks[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<numClocks; i++) {
            holder.ratingClocks[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```